# How to create an object with int and String arrays in the constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have a `Student` class setting up an object like so:

```
private String name;
private int num, level;
String[] module = {"CSC1011", "CSC1004", "CSC1010"};
int[] marks = {-1, -1, -1};

public Student(String sName, int sNum, int sLevel, String[] sModule, int[] sMarks) {
    name = sName;
    num = sNum;
    level = sLevel;
    module = sModule;
    marks = sMarks;
}
```

I'm not sure how to test this in a main file?

```
Student a = new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, "CSC1010", 10);
```

or

```
Student a = new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, module[0], marks[1]);
```

I was also wondering how to create a getter or setter for arrays?

Comment: Where is the issue? What you want to test in main file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters as `new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, "CSC1010", 10)` or `new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, module[0], marks[1])`, then the last two parameters aren't arrays. They're just a plain String and a plain int, so it should be:

```
public Student(String sName, int sNum, int sLevel, String sModule, int sMarks) {
```

Also, you don't need this `s` stuff in front of the variable names. The [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword is used for distinguishing between a variable within a method and a variable of the same name on the current object. The better way to write that constructor is:

```
public Student(String name, int num, int level, String module, int marks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.num = num;
    this.level = level;
    this.module = module;
    this.marks = marks;
}
```

(And also change the class variables `module` and `marks` so they are not arrays.)

If `module` and `marks` *are* actually supposed to be arrays, then you have a different problem. First of all, these default values of the class-level variables aren't being used, so they are pointless:

```
String[] module = {"CSC1011", "CSC1004", "CSC1010"};
int[] marks = {-1, -1, -1};
```

That should simply be:

```
private String[] modules;
private int[] marks;
```

To invoke the constructor when those two parameters are arrays, use syntax like the following:

```
new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, new String[] { "CSC1010" }, new int[] { 10 });
```

For several values:

```
new Student("Bill", 401033, 1,
    new String[] { "CSC1011", "CSC1004", "CSC1010" },
    new int[] { 10, 20, 30 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called when you create a new object of the class.

```
public Student(String sName, int sNum, int sLevel, String[] sModule, int[] sMarks) {
    name = sName;
    num = sNum;
    level = sLevel;
    module = sModule;
    marks = sMarks;
    System.out.println("Number:-"+num);
}
```

Add `sysout` to write values which are passed in parameter of constructor.
Add this statement to get array of string.

```
public String[] getModule()
{
    return module;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this simple one-liner:

```
Student a = new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, new String[]{"string1", "string2"}, new int[] {1,2});
```

This initializes new arrays right before passing them to your argument constructor.

Getting and setting is as simple as:

```
public String[] getSModule() {
    return sModule;  // your String array
}

public String[] setSModule(String[] module) {
    this.sModule=sModule
}
```

**UPDATE.**

To access and print single element from the array (answering to your comment), use:

```
System.out.println(a.getSModule()[1]);
```

To print everything stored in an array,  use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getSModule());
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks everyone. I have no errors now but I'm getting really weird output? public class Student_Tester {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Student a = new Student("Bill Rodger", 40103352, 1, new String[] {"CSC1010" }, new int[] { 10 });
  System.out.println(a.getMark());
  System.out.println(a.getModuleCode());
 }
} For this I got, [I@174487c8
[Ljava.lang.String;@69b3a74d as my output.

Comment: Just copied it to my IDE. You are trying to print the whole table whilst you should print only one item from it, so instead of typing System.out.println(a.getMark()); use System.out.println(a.getMark()[1]); See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, sMarks and sModules are arrays. So you should pass in arrays:

```
    String[] modules = {"CSC1011", "CSC1004", "CSC1010"}; 
    int[] marks = {-1, -1, -1};

    Student a = new Student("Bill", 401033, 1, modules, marks);
```

Here's how to create a getter and setter for an array:

```
private String[] marks = null;

public String[] getMarks() {
    return marks;
}

public void setMarks(String[] marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
}
```